# JSON Encode Failing With No Error (Blank Page)

Tags: php, json, pdo, encoding

I'm selecting all data from a table using **fetchAll()** via PDO from an **MSSQL** DB. I'm simply trying to do a **json_encode** on the results however when I do a json_encode I get a blank page when using an echo to display the results. I can do a var dump on the same array that I'm trying to encode and get all the data. I get no errors in the php logs and doing a json_last_error gives me NOTHING. Perhaps someone can see something in the following code that I'm not.

```
$sth = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM dbo.Devices");
$sth->execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll();

//var_dump($result);
echo json_encode($result);
```

I've also tried doing a utf8_encode on the data before passing it to the json_encode thinking that it was a character encoding issue and that was well gives me a blank page with no error message.

**EDIT:**

If I grab one row using fetch vs fetchAll it coverts the data fine.

So this works:

```
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

But this doesn't:

```
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: In your place I would edit the other question instead of adding another one.

Comment: To me, this seemed to be a different topic. I'd like the ability to remove the other question.

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)` to see if there are any warnings.

Comment: is `var_dump($result);` showing the fetched data correctly?

Comment: Yes, var_dump is proper.

Comment: Please post contetn of var_dump for $sth->fetchAll()